# android.view.WindowLeaked: because of this dialog.getWindow.setBackgroundDrawableResource

Tags: android

android.view.WindowLeaked: because of this `dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);`

Even though I'm not fnishing activity anywhere

```
E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Activity.AddReminderActivity has leaked window DecorView@e38a2fa[AddReminderActivity] that was originally added here
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:534)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:346)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:94)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:329)
        at com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Utils.CategoryDialog.showCategoryDialog(CategoryDialog.java:56)
        at com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Activity.AddReminderActivity.onClick(AddReminderActivity.java:760)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6608)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6585)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:785)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25921)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at
```

Comment: I think you are not dismissing the dialog in onDestroy() method.

Comment: Check Activity isFinishing() or not?

Comment: @Anisha Singh Have you go it?

Comment: @SibinDavis I'm not finishing activity

Comment: @NancyY   I'm not finishing activity

Comment: @AnishaSingh ??

Answer (score 0):

Call `dismiss()` for the `Dialog` instance you created before exiting your `Activity`.

Use this in `onPause()` or `onDestroy()`